# Setting default value in NSUserDefaults ios8 using swift

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, nsuserdefaults, settings.bundle

How to make the toogle switch to be ON?

Also I read that if the user run the app for the first time the Default Value will not be used. How to check that?

In settings bundle

[image: In settings bundle]

In settings app

[image: In settings app]

In AppDelegate

```
let defaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
let showEnabledString:Bool = defaults.boolForKey("enabled_string");
println(showEnabledString); // true

 let appDefaults: NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: "YES", forKey: "enabled_string");
```

// This code also doesnt change the appearance  in the Settings App

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(appDefaults as [NSObject : AnyObject]);
           NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `registerDefaults:` ? https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/registerDefaults:

Comment: the Enabled switch is still OFF, i know if get the value will be false or nil, but by default the appearance should be ON

Comment: How are you setting the switch state once you have the boolean? Or is that your real question? `setOn(_:animated:)` https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISwitch/setOn:animated:

Comment: But the switch is in Settings App(by apple) where i can see all settings for my app. I don't need to use setOn(_:animated:)

Comment: Given that there are multiple moving pieces, there is a tutorial in Apple's docs that includes switches... have you (re-)gone through it to see what, if anything, you're doing differently? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html (Look for "Configuring a Settings Page")

Comment: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/05/18/adding-a-settings-bundle-to-an-iphone-app.html - example code

Comment: The code is okay, but this switch must be ON by default. Because right now the user open the settings and switch is OFF, but i want to start with ON and then he can change it to OFF

Comment: "One thing that is poorly explained in the Apple documentation is the use of the DefaultValue field. You would think that this sets the value that your application will see when your App runs for the first time. Unfortunately this is not the case. The default value is used to set the initial position of the toggle switch in the settings application." this part is not true, because is not ON

Comment: While errors in Apple's docs are certainly possible, the more reasonable suggestion is that some other piece of the puzzle isn't configured correctly. That's why I suggested you go through the tutorial _thoroughly_, step-by-step to see where, if at all, what you're doing differs.

Comment: I deleted the app and build it again and this time it worked.

Comment: Score one for entropy, then. At least it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("enabled_string") as? Bool != true {
   yourSwitchName.setOn(false, animated: false)
}else{
   yourSwitchName.setOn(true, animated: false)
}
```

Put the above in your `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`. This is how I set my switches at least.